# Get value from Firebase while extending ArrayList

Tags: android, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to work with Firebase and Lists.

My objects contains a class extending ArrayList such as:

```
MyClass {
    // other fields here
    public static class List extends ArrayList<Foo> {};
}
```

If I try to upload a `List` item to Firebase database, it works out of the box and no problem are faced.

The problem come when I try to retrieve these `List`s from the server, such as:

```
MyClass mMyClass = dataSnapshot.getValue(MyClass.class);
```

This throws an exception saying

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.util.ArrayList to type mypackage.MyClass$List

The only possible thing working for me is to revert back to `ArrayList<Foo>` instead of extending it from another class.

Is there any other possible way to cast without problems?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [GenericTypeIndicator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/GenericTypeIndicator) to read the list data as a generic collection:

```
GenericTypeIndicator<MyClass.List> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<MyClass.List>() {};
MyClass.List mList = dataSnapshot.getValue(t);
```

I'm not sure whether this will work with an inner class. You may need to declare `List` as its own stand-alone type. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744224/how-to-retrieve-a-list-object-from-the-firebase-in-android) for more examples.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: I'm curious how this worked out for you with your generic list being a member of the class you want to read. I looked for a solution but only found [this unanswered question.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41948309/213156)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try getting the value as ArrayList and then casting it to your class. 
Something like:

`MyClass mMyClass = (MyClass) dataSnapshot.getValue(ArrayList.class);`

Comment: My problem is that the class 'List' is inside the class which I'm passing to the 'getValue()' method

Answer (score 0):

User `addEventValueListener` for getting arraylist of particular reference

Comment: I'm sorry, I cutted it away from the post since I thought it was boilerplate, I'm already doing this in a ValueEventListener.

Comment: then what happen..?

Comment: As the question say, I'm getting a DatabaseException since firebase is trying to cast an ArrayList<Foo> to a List class which is extending ArrayList<Foo>

Comment: use direct `dataSnapshot.getValue(List.class);`